# How to detect the DeviceType(Desktop/Mobile/..).and Show the respective Mode of a login user/customer

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller

I have written some code, in that if a user login through the mobile, then it should get detected and for Mobile or Tablet.

I have tried for Both, But I am getting result for the BrowserName and Version.

```
// Getting browser `name`
var BrowserName = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser.Browser;

// Getting Version `No Of Browser`
var Version = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser.Version;

var DeviceTypes = "";           
var DeviceModel = "";
```

Like if a user login using Samsung Mobile then t should return Samsing Device name and Model whatever like Note 7 or whatever.

Comment: HTTP doesnt support that, you can only get the User-Agent (Browser) details.

Comment: @Roy is there any other way to get that Details of user.

Comment: Actually, i feel it is a privacy issue also, the details are not added in HTTP protocol for a reason. If you still insist of knowing it, then you have to rely on a Custom Mobile/Desktop App to get the data and post it to your api. Make sure you follow the privacy rules and customers are notified about data collection while doing so. if you are not interested in per-user device details, you can also use Google Analytics tools which can give an overall picture.

Comment: @Roy var DeviceTypess = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser.MobileDeviceManufacturer.ToLower().ToString();
            var DeviceModels = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser.MobileDeviceModel;         This is the code i have written, but while i m debugging at that time i will show the devicename and model for apple product only, what would b the issue.

Comment: You should understand the HTTP as a protocol first,When your application get the request, all the header has is a User-Agent header to know about the Client. To my knowledge .Net might be using a lookup to know about the browser capabilities based on the user-agent. i wont completely rely on User-Agent as this can be overridden manually in case of firefox, others im not sure. You can check the User-Agent documentation to understand various default values that can be shared by different clients.